# URL - Http Post Request with AJAX

Tags: magento-2.1, ajax, http-request

I am developing a new module for my company in `**Magento 2**` and i require an AJAX Http post request, however I cannot find the correct URL.

I have all of my controllers currently set up however, when I send the request in JQuery I receive a 404 error.

File structure:

```
->Controller

---->Post

--------->Message.php

--------->User.php

---->Get

--------->Threads.php

--------->Messages.php
```

For example, if i am trying to send a request to Post/Message.php, What would the correct URL be?

Thanks.

Comment: are you working for magento-1 or magento 2?

Comment: Magento 2, sorry I will update it now

Comment: I post the answer, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the correct path of your above things.

1. Magento_domain/extension_frontend_router/post/message
2. Magento_domain/extension_frontend_router/post/user
3. Magento_domain/extension_frontend_router/get/threads
4. Magento_domain/extension_frontend_router/get/messages

Comment: hi Dhiren,

In my frontend/routes.xml file, the front name is "forum". does this mean that the url i want to hit is www.mywebsite.com/forum/post/message?

because this is the one showing a 404

Comment: yes "www.mywebsite.com/forum/post/message" right URL if everything implement properly.

Comment: If my answer help you, please accept so it will help other in community.

Comment: this does not seem to be working for me, I have been testing it for a while and cannot make it work

Comment: First check have implement all the things proper?